# Access value of dropdown that has multiples based on one model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code that creates a listing of calendar entries for the courtroom. Each individual case has a "status" dropdown that is set by the judge after the hearing is finished. I need to save this information to the database. I have added ng-change and it fires the function I ask it to. However, how can I get the selected value of the "status" dropdown that triggered the ng-change?

The code for my view is as follows:

```
<div ng-controller="CaseListCtrl">
    <div class="row" ng-show="$parent.loggedin">
        <div class="col-sm-12 calselectrow">
            <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar calicon"></span>

                <input type="text" id="calpick" ng-model="date" jdatepicker />
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar calclick"></i>

                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary flat-edge">>></a>

                <span class="bluedept">Department:</span>
                <select class="selectpicker deptpicker" id="deptSelect" selectpicker data-ng-model="department" ng-change="getCalendar();">
                    <option ng-repeat="department in departments">{{department.CourtRoom}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" ng-show="$parent.loggedin">
        <div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 caselist" ng-model="cases" ng-repeat-start="case in cases |  orderBy: ['sequence', 'AmPm', 'Sched_Time', 'Case_Number']">
                <div class="sequence">
                    <input type=text class="seq-box" size="1" value="{{case.SeqNumber}}" />
                    <!-- Add hidden field to hold the CalendarID value for updating the sequence later-->
                    <input type="hidden" name="CalendarID_{{case.Case.CaseNumber}}" value="{{case.DailyEventCaseID}}" />
                </div>
                <div class="casetitle">
                    <span class="caselink">{{case.Case.CaseNumber}}</span>
                    <a href="calendar" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Calendar" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger calicon-view" tooltip>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="documents/{{case.Case.CaseNumber}}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Documents" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger calicon-view" tooltip>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="parties/{{case.Case.CaseNumber}}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Parties" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger calicon-view" tooltip>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                    </a>
                    <select class="form-control input-mini" id="caseStatus" name="caseStatus" ng-model="case.StatusID" ng-change="setItem(case.DailyEventCaseID, case.Case.CaseNumber, case.EventDate, 'STA');" ng-options="caseStatus.Status for caseStatus in caseStatus track by caseStatus.Status" required></select>
                        {{case.Case.CaseTitle}}
</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 caselist-bottom">
                <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-1" ng-repeat="event in case.Events">
                    <div class="hearing-time">{{case.EventDate | date: 'h:mm a'}}</div>
                    <div class="hearing-title">{{event.EventName}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-repeat-end></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: simplest way is to use ngOptions: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: Couldn't you just check `case.StatusID` in the `ng-change` function to get the status?

Comment: @o4ohel I am already using ngOptions as evidenced by the sample code `ng-options="caseStatus.Status for caseStatus in caseStatus track by caseStatus.Status'

Comment: @RalphWiggum When I check case.StatusID it shows as undefined.

Comment: Can you just pass it straight into the `setItem` function, maybe something like `setItem(case.DailyEventCaseID, case.Case.CaseNumber, case.EventDate, case.StatusID, 'STA')`? Alternatively, you could just pass the entire object: `setItem(case, 'STA')`...

Comment: What's with the `ng-model="cases"` on the div tag on the ngRepeat? Try removing that. Also unrelated, you should change `>>` to `&raquo;` instead or `&gt;&gt;`

Comment: @RalphWiggum I gave that a try earlier today and it gives me the value that comes in from the database and not the value I change it to. Very strange indeed.

Comment: `ng-model="cases"` is the model that is being iterated through in the ng-repeat to make the calendar data display correctly. The drop down in question is created from the `caseStatus` model which contains a lookup list of Status values. In the cases model it has a `StatusID` value that gets returned from the database. What I want is to be able to set the dropdown to the `caseStatus` model for populating all the values, but then update the cases.`StatusID` when I change the value. I then need to save that to the database.

Comment: If you print out `{{case.StatusID}}` just after the `<select>` does it change the text when you change the selected value in the dropdown?

Comment: What happens is it displays some JSON as follows:

`{"StatusID":3,"Status":"Default"}`

This is clearly the value from caseStatus, a model that contains those two items.

Comment: OK, so I figured out the issue here. I am passing this into the function and at that point I read StatusID.StatusID and I get what I am looking for. However, I notice that the dropdown doesn't load with the initial value of case.StatusID. Any ideas why that wold be? @RalphWiggum

Comment: I'm not really sure. My guess would be the values for the ngOptions and the initial value of `case.StatusID` aren't matching?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had to modify the `ng-options`. This line of code:

```
<select class="form-control input-mini" id="caseStatus" name="caseStatus" ng-model="case.StatusID" ng-change="setItem(case.DailyEventCaseID, case.Case.CaseNumber, case.EventDate, 'STA');" ng-options="caseStatus.Status for caseStatus in caseStatus track by caseStatus.Status" required></select>
```

Got changed to:

```
<select class="form-control input-mini" id="caseStatus" name="caseStatus" ng-model="case.Status" ng-change="setItem(case.DailyEventCaseID, case.Case.CaseNumber, case.EventDate, 'STA');" ng-options="caseStatus.Status for caseStatus in caseStatus track by caseStatus.Status" required></select>
```

That wired everything up correctly and the save worked.